# Overflow не работает без указания высоты

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

Имеется выезжающий блок с уведомлениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красными выделены уведомления.

Сейчас высота всего блока 100% и при уменьшении экрана\увеличении количества уведомлений появляется скролл.
Появилась надобность сделать высоту уведомлений не 100%, а по контенту. Соотвественно при уменьшении масштаба или увеличении количества сообщений перестал работать скроллинг.

Неработающий пример тут:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-chihiro-9u93g?file=/src/App.js

Как в данном случае правильно ограничить высоту блока уведомлений по количеству этих самых уведомлений, сохраняя функционал скроллинга?

Comment: Работающий пример это хорошо. Вы бы и не работающий показали - вам бы быстрее подсказали.

Comment: @АлександрРогонов изменил sandbox по ссылке, теперь там неработающий пример без скроллинга

Comment: @R.Key попробуйте использовать min-height и max-height

Comment: Ну честно говоря, понятнее не стало. Как вы понимаете, ни кто кроме вас о вашем проекте постоянно не думает. Добавили не работающий пример - отлично, спасибо, но думаете кто-то помнит как выглядел работающий?:) Вообще, для того, чтобы обсудить верстку не нужен проект на React. Просто прямо здесь вставьте пример HTML+CSS работающий и не работающий вариант. Если бы вы сразу так сделал вам бы давным давно ответили. Еще бы я порекомендовал вам перечитать ваш пост, там тоже не все ясно "Уменьшение масштаба" это о чём?